# Bold text in a table when I didn't tell it to be

Tags: html, css

I have this really weird issue. When ever I run this page on my server the text of the table comes out bold when I haven't told it anywhere to be bold. The buttons that say Logout and back at the top come out without bold but the whole table is bold. Its really annoying me now! Please help!

```
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<title>RHS Year 13 - Administration</title>

<link href="style_ric.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"> <img src="header.jpg" width="260px" height="50"/>
</div>
<h1>Administration Panel
</h1>
<p class="form"><a href="users.php?logout=yes">Logout</a> - <a href="view.php">Back</a></p>
<h1>
  <hr />



<?php

include_once 'database_login.php'; 


if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY last_name ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query ($con, $sql); 

echo '</p>';
echo '<table border="0" class="form">';
echo '<tr><td>Student ID</td><td>Last Name</td><td>First Name</td><td>Form Class</td></tr>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row["student_id"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row["last_name"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row["first_name"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row["form_class"] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
}; 
echo '</table>';

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(last_name) FROM login"; 
$rs_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20); 

  echo '<p class="form">';
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
              echo '<a href="users.php?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>'; 
}; 

echo '</p>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

p {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}

h1 {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.form {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;


}

.nopadding {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.italics_note {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style:italic;
}

.error {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#F00;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.done {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#060;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header {
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#020154;
    color: #000000;
}

#error {
    width:200px;
    height:14px;
    padding:1px;
    background-color:#F00;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Check with `firebug` or chrome `inspect element` to see why it is bold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You opened a `<h1>` tag which you didn't close. Since your `logout` button is before the `<h1>` tag it appears normal. And the bold attribute of your `<h1>` gets applied to all other elements.

Comment: Thanks for that!! Its been a long night :P

Comment: not a problem. You may want to use a proper ID and stay strict to indentation to avoid such issues in the future. :)